# Class not registered inside a Windows Container

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, docker, windows-container

I have an application that I want to get into a Windows Container. While running the app, I get the following error:

> error : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}  failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I believe it is related to the fact that I need to use Microsoft.mshtml.dll but it is not registered cause there's no Internet Explorer inside the container.

So I have many questions about this.
1) Is my assumption correct?
2) What are my options?

Here's what I've tried so far:
Add-WindowsFeature for Internet Explorer 11 -> does not work
Copy a dll inside the container and try to register it (assuming that's the only one), can't be done, regasm fails.
Exported that class registry path from my dev machine and try to import it in the container. Does not work because it says it cannot access the registry.

I'm running out of ideas... again, assuming I'm on the right track.

Comment: Does your application have any other COM references? How did you determine it was mshtml.dll?

Comment: Yes, IE will not be available and all of UI libraries as result inside container

Comment: @Chris not that I can remember,,, I googled the CLSID

Comment: @GregorySuvalian what are my options, can you think of one? any suggestion will be tested... there are no bad ideas at the moment :)

Comment: I beleive there is much bigger container image is available for insider, you can try that one (https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/06/28/microsoft_releases_new_containerised_cut_of_windows_server/)

Comment: thank you @GregorySuvalian, will try that image and come back with my outcome

Comment: @sebagomez did you resolve this?

Comment: I did, by using Chromimum instead of IE :(

Comment: Did you found a solution for this issue ?